# Unable to set a format for values on a heatmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I'm using highcharts to create a heatmap. I'd like to have the values on the heatmap with a % sign as suffix. Here's the snippet:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Sales per employee',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [[0,0,10],[0,1,19],[0,2,8],[0,3,24],[0,4,67],[1,0,92],[1,1,58],[1,2,78],[1,3,117],[1,4,48]],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'black',
                format: '{value}%',
            }
        }]
```

The `{value}%` is not working as value seems to be empty. If I change that to `{y}%` it works except it's using the y value for the heatmap (not the actual value at that position). Should I be using something other than dataLabels for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `formatter` option instead :

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    color: 'black',
    //format: '{value} %',
    formatter: function(){
         return this.point.value + ' %';
     }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8pq8w5h/)

Answer (score 0):

To make it work use `{point.value}%` instead of `{value}%`:

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  format: '{point.value}%'  
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/0k0hc3j5/